# Can the tag needed for my mis-tagged question be created?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, specific-question

I just posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344215/can-the-learn-spell-spell-be-used-to-learn-high-level-item-creation-spells).

It should be tagged [warlords-battlecry-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warlords-battlecry-2), but the tag doesn't yet exist and I lack the rep to create it.

Would someone with 300+ rep mind creating the tag and applying it to my question?